# Delete several characters in an NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, char, nsstring

How can I programmatically make this `NSString`:

```
(
    548760
)
```

It's basically:

```
(           548760       )
```

... but that should not matter.

To this `NSString`:

```
548760
```

Comment: Are the parenthesis to be excluded?

Comment: Yes, thats the JSON value I get. I need it to write into a `UILabel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the string will be the same format every time:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSString *formattedString;
formattedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
formattedString = [formattedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
```

Comment: -[__NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a16100

Comment: This is occuring because `stringByReplacingOccurencesWithString:withString` is a method available to `NSString`, not `NSArray`. You need to do `[(NSString *)[array objectAtIndex:i] stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];

Comment: `NSArray *items = [json valueForKeyPath:@"a.b.c"];`
`NSString * string = [items valueForKey:@"value"];` That's what I do. Your second approach does not work either ... >.<

Comment: @Darwin, perhaps `valueForKey:@"value"` is an `NSArray`

Comment: Solved: `NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[items valueForKey:@"value"]];`, then your approaches. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *trimmed =
    [yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
             [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSLog(@"trimmed: '%@'", trimmed);
```

Comment: Same thing here: -[__NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a16100

Comment: You didn't say it was an array. You said NSString.

Comment: Solved: `NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[items valueForKey:@"value"]];`, then your approaches. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is an array. If so just get

```
NSString *string = [yourArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: No, I found the solutions, look on my comment.

Comment: I still think your 'items' is an array.

Comment: You're right, but the problem was, that `valueForKey: blabla` was not an `NSString`, just raw data. I had to convert it into `NSString` to make use of your approaches.